# tfplugindocs terraform document generation error

Tags: terraform

I am new to golang and terraform plugin development. I was trying to generate plugin documentation by 'tfplugindocs' and I am still getting errors..

below is the output of 'tfplugindocs' execution.

my plugin is still under development and not registered with terraform

what can be the cause for this error..

```
% go run github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-docs/cmd/tfplugindocs
rendering website for provider "hashicups"
exporting schema from Terraform
compiling provider "hashicups"
getting Terraform binary
running terraform init
getting provider schema
**Error executing command: unable to generate website:
Error: Could not load plugin


Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be
located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/hashicups" to
obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message: open : no such file or
directory

This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol.**
```

exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I started getting this error.

It appears to have started when I commented out the `Address` field in the `providerserver.ServeOpts` struct in `main.go` like this:

```
    opts := providerserver.ServeOpts{
        // TODO: Update this string with the published name of your provider.
        // Address: "registry.terraform.io/davidalpert/myproject",
        Debug:   debug,
    }
```

Once I uncommented that `Address` field I was able to run the build (which runs generate, which runs `tfplugindocs`) without error.

```
    opts := providerserver.ServeOpts{
        // TODO: Update this string with the published name of your provider.
        Address: "registry.terraform.io/davidalpert/myproject",
        Debug:   debug,
    }
```

My plugin is not published yet either, so that `Address` value is not valid, but that doesn't seem to matter so long as the `Address` field is set to override the default.